# How will create the updater & repair window's in NSIS using NULL SCRIPT

Tags: window, nsis, repair, updaters

I'm trying to create the updater window and repair window's

Installation installer i'm done with functionality & window creation side. But, The updater & repair window's how will create Functionality side i'm done. My question is how will create the window

I try to create the customized window. But getting error's and window also not came while click the exe

Comment: This makes no sense, please rephrase your question.